Making a Soil Moisture Sensor, simulation error in Proteus
So I made this soil moisture sensor simulation in Proteus using C, in Keil µVision 5. I cant point out what is wrong in the code. Can someone help me?
It uses a soil sensor module, ADC, 8051 and an LED that blinks when moisture content is below a threshold value.
Loaded the hex file onto Proteus, but it is showing an error while trying to simulate.

I tried to make an LED blink whenever the moisture content was lower than the threshold value. But when I loaded the hex file onto Proteus, it didn't give an output. It gave this error:
AVR: Program property is not defined.
Here is the C program:
#include <reg52.h>

#define input P3

sbit LED = P1^0; 
sbit rd = P2^4;
sbit wr = P2^3;
sbit intr = P2^2;

void delay(unsigned int time_ms) {
    unsigned int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < time_ms; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 112; j++);
}

void init_ADC() {
    P3 = 0xFF; 
}

unsigned int read_ADC() {
    unsigned int adc = 0x00;
    rd = 1;
    wr = 0;
    delay(10);
    wr = 1;
    while (intr == 1);
    rd = 0;
    intr = 1;
    delay(10);
    adc = input;
    return adc;
}

void main() {
    unsigned int val;
    init_ADC();
    while (1) {
        val=read_ADC();
        if (val < 50) {
            LED = 1;
            delay(500);   
            LED = 0;  
            delay(500);  
        } else {
            LED = 0;  
        }
    }
}


This looks like a Proteus setup issue. Have you searched the documentation? What does it say? Please [edit] your question to add your findings.

You should insert a resistor in series with your LED. In real life, without such it will burn the LED and/or the port pin.

AVR is not 8051? Why use either, do you also use a computer from the 1990s? These are museum-worthy cores.

@Lundin We know you as advocate against "retro" stuff. :-D Anyway, apparently some poor souls are tasked to use such. -- The AT89C51 is an 8051, not an AVR, even if it is manufactured by Atmel/Microchip.
